# class cast exception on running HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, classcastexception

I had my Pojo class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="INSTITUTE")
public class Institute {    
    private int id;
    private Member member_id;
    private String yearoffrom;
    private Date created_date;
    private Country country_id;
    private State state_id;
    private City city_id;
    private String josh_rating;
    private String institute_type;
    private Clob about; 
    private String tags;
    private String natureofbus;
    private String placement;
    private String placement_percentage;
    private String affiliations;
    private String scholarship;
    private String keyword;
    private String avg_salary;
    private String document_path;
    private String contact_person;
    private String address;
    private String source;
    private String zip;
    private int is_active;
    private int is_deleted;
    private AdminUser created_by_id;
    private AdminUser verified_by_id;
```

I am selecting only few columns through HQL

```
select inst.id,inst.member_id.name as institutename,inst.institute_type,inst.city_id.name as cityname,inst.state_id.name as statename,inst.country_id.name as countryname,inst.created_by_id.username as createdby,inst.verified_by_id.username as verifiedby  from Institute inst
```

On running the code, I found that Hibernate query is generated by Application and is returning the resultset. But when I want to traverse the list by this code:

```
for(Institute bean : institutelist) {
```

Application throws an ClassCastException.

How to resolve this problem?

Following is the stracktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/EducationNew] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to education.bean.Institute] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to education.bean.Institute
    at education.service.InstituteListingService.getInstituteList_HQL(InstituteListingService.java:45)
    at education.controller.LoginController.validateUser(LoginController.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

HQL Query:
Hibernate: `select * from ( select institute0_.id as col_0_0_, member1_.name as col_1_0_, institute0_.institute_type as col_2_0_, city2_.name as col_3_0_, state3_.name as col_4_0_, country4_.name as col_5_0_, adminuser5_.username as col_6_0_, adminuser6_.username as col_7_0_ from INSTITUTE institute0_, MEMBER member1_, City city2_, State state3_, Country country4_, AdminUser adminuser5_, AdminUser adminuser6_ where institute0_.member_id=member1_.id and institute0_.city_id=city2_.id and institute0_.state_id=state3_.id and institute0_.country_id=country4_.id and institute0_.created_by_id=adminuser5_.id and institute0_.verified_by_id=adminuser6_.id ) where rownum <= ?`

Comment: Show us the stack trace.

Comment: Finally, show us your HQL query.

Comment: Make your iterator variable be an Object, then test its type and cast to the appropriate type once you have it.  (Presumably Object is being returned to mark a null result or some such.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query currently returns you a result list of objects which aren't instances of Institute - due to aliases like inst.member_id.name as institutename, selecting Member name instead of Member itself etc.

How to fix that? There are few solutions, but I would try to selecting Institute into new Institute:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("Select new Institute(inst.id, inst.name, inst.stuff...) from Institute inst");
```

Full example can be found at [here](http://emrpms.blogspot.com/2012/06/select-only-few-columns-in-hibernate.html)

Other solution is to use Hibernate [projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection).

Comment: creating an Institute object (which is also used as an entity) like that is going to cause a lot of confusion: When someone get hold of an Institute instance, he simply dunno if it is an entity under control of JPA or is simply a detached value object.

Comment: Thats why we create Dses and Dtos classes.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said the example in the answer is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are selectively selecting some attributes instead of selecting the whole entity, the return is in fact an list of tuple (`List<Object[]>`).  Each entry in the list (which is an `Object[]`) represent one row of result.

Therefore your loop should look like

```
List<Object[]> results = (List<Object[]>) yourQuery.list();
for (Object[] result : results) {
    //....
}
```

Quoted from http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-select :

> Queries can return multiple objects and/or properties as an array of
>   type Object[]:
>
> ```
> select mother, offspr, mate.name from DomesticCat as mother
> inner join mother.mate as mate
> left outer join mother.kittens as offspr
> ```

More way to handle selecting selective properties is also described in the quoted link